# Android: read and process and display text file from internet

Tags: android, android-activity, process, textview

I have a text file on internet with foramt like:

```
abc,efg
```

I can read and display this content in textview, but I need display "abc" in one textview and "efg" in another textview on the next activity and I can't!!!!!!!
please help me!

Comment: elia you have to try harder :)) then post some code as Prmths suggests. You will get help here, but only if you show everyone else some effort first!  (We do know how to do this :))

Comment: is this the name of your file?.... if is why you don use string.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String yourString = "abc,efg";
String[] array = yourString.split(",");
String abc = array[0];
String efg = array[1];
```